# Can not uninstall VMWare Workstation Player conventionally

Tags: vmware

I've tried `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player` before, but the app is still there. It can be seen in App Menu, and can EVEN be launched and used, but it is not listed in `vmware-installer -l` - it only shows VMWare Workstation PRO (i installed it right away after presumably uninstalling Workstation Player). I couldn't find any relevant folders in `usr/bin` as well. What can i do? I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu just for that.

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: I think it will delete the Workstation Pro, which i currently use, and not the Player, which is ghosted somewhere.

Comment: Yes it does, it sits right next to Workstation Pro. You can see on my screenshot two open instances - one for Pro and one for Player.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.3K Nov 13 21:26 /usr/bin/vmplayer`

Comment: You can run `locate vmplayer` and see if related files are still there. If they exists, delete them. The shortcuts are located as vmware-player.desktop in `/usr/share/applications/` and `/usr/local/share/applications/`

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you.

Comment: Turns out Player is a vital component for Workstation - it is considered a component that can not be removed. That is utterly stupid, but what can i do. I deleted the shortcut from App Menu with your advice, that's better than nothing, i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Player is a vital component for Workstation - it is considered a component that can not be removed. That is utterly stupid, but what can i do. I deleted the shortcut from App Menu from `/usr/share/applications/` and `/usr/local/share/applications/`, that's better than nothing, I guess.